# Is it possible to build side-by-side feature comparison table using flutter dart? how?

Tags: dart, flutter

Just wonder if the standard library  (and how) can Flutter dart build a side-by-side column wise tables (like those feature comparison tables for, said different models of android phones, etc).  Note that we also need it to be web accessibility so the talk-back / voice over need to read the screen column by column.

Comment: Does the Table widget provide the functionality you need? https://youtu.be/_lbE0wsVZSw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this and modify things according to your needs.

[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Testing")),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
      child: Table(
        columnWidths: {
          0: FlexColumnWidth(),
          1: FlexColumnWidth(0.02),
          2: FlexColumnWidth(),
        },
        children: [
          TableRow(children: [_buildBox("Android is cool"), SizedBox(), _buildBox("iOS is hot")]),
          TableRow(children: [_buildBox("Android is flexible"), SizedBox(), _buildBox("iOS isn't")]),
          TableRow(children: [_buildBox("Android is dashing"), SizedBox(), _buildBox("No comments")]),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildBox(String title) {
  return Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.blue,
      border: Border(top: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
    ),
    height: 44,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
      title,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: tks for your contribution.  BTW, will the talkback read columnwise if implemented in your suggested way (i.e. read all column 1 first, and then column 2)

Comment: I am sorry I haven't used that option before, so I can't tell you if that will work, but I assume it would.